# Flutter on Yocto?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to develop a flutter application on Yocto with Docker or without it? I'm asking that because planning to use an IMX series processor and want to develop a flutter application.
If yes, how can I? Please give a document.

Comment: This should give you a pretty good idea: https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-on-raspberry-pi-mostly-from-scratch-2824c5e7dcb1

Comment: Hello @Gokhan Sahin, did you manage to find any information? I'm interested as well un using Flutter on Yocto environment. Maybe we can address the topic.

Comment: Hi @Giulia, I haven't found any information about it so that I had to give up.